# DateTime add 1 day doesnt' work with 29 October 2023

Tags: dart, date

I can't get this following simple DART code working with the date 29 October 2023 (it seems to add just 23 hours)

```
    void main() {
    var a = DateTime.parse("2023-10-29");

      var b = a.add(Duration(days: 1));
      print(b.toString());
    }
```

Anybody can help me understand this?
Thanks

I was expecting just 30 october 2023 as output

[DartPad screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/994cO.png)

Comment: It do work for me, it gives `2023-10-30 00:00:00.000` as result

Comment: In the night from 29 October to 30 October Daylight changes from summertime to wintertime  (P.S. You should add more info than "I was expecting a different behaviour", just to make clear that you really are expecting 24 hours later to be returned)

Comment: I have two videos on the subject of dates in dart https://youtu.be/usFSVUEadyo and https://youtu.be/LpoBYgzKVwU

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now! Sorry but I'm a beginner and it is my first question on StackOverflow

Comment: To correct the change in timezone, do:   `print(a.add(Duration(days: 1)).add(Duration(hours: a.timeZoneOffset.inHours - a.add(Duration(days: 1)).timeZoneOffset.inHours )));`